# Load file in Today extension

Tags: ios, ios8, today-extension, nsfilecoordinator

I've been trying to create a Today extension that needs access to a `.plist` file in the documents directory. I have setup the App group for both the app and the extension.

While I have seen examples for `NSUserDefaults`, I couldn't find anything for accessing files.

I tried accessing the file like this (which works in the app itself)

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
        .DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
let documentsDirectory = paths[0] as String
let filePath = "\(documentsDirectory)/config.plist"

if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(filePath) // false
{
… 
}
```

But I get the following error messages in the console:

```
Warning: CFFIXED_USER_HOME is not set!  It should be set to the simulated home directory.
Failed to inherit CoreMedia permissions from 59919: (null)
```

The documentation says something about using `NSFileCoordinator` and `NSFilePresenter`. I couldn't find out how to use them though. I'm sure I'll need to tell them the app group identifier somewhere but I don't where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work. Since I don't need to write the file from the extension, I don't think I need to use `NSFileCoordinator`. Turns out `NSFileManager` has a method `containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier()` for retrieving the container URL.

```
let manager = NSFileManager()
let containerURL = manager.containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("group.MyGroupIdentifier")

let filePath = "\(containerURL.path)/config.plist"
let settings = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: filePath)
```

Comment: Have you tried this with the device locked? Does the file still load for you? It works great for me as long as the phone isn't locked, but if I have a passcode on no data comes through. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25938178/load-file-in-today-extension-when-device-is-locked

Comment: @ccwasden No problems here…