# Load file in Today extension when device is locked

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager, today-extension

In my today extension with my device unlocked, this line of code works as expected, returning the data from the image path:

```
let imageData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path)
```

However when my device is locked with a passcode, it returns nil. Is there any way to access images in the file system when the device is locked? I can access UserDefaults just fine, but not files in the directory for my shared group. Here is how I am creating the path, calling `imagePath`, which is correctly populated with the path I expect in both cases:

```
func rootFilePath() -> String? {
    let manager = NSFileManager()
    let containerURL = manager.containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier(GROUP_ID)
    if let unwrappedURL = containerURL {
        return unwrappedURL.path
    }
    else {
        return nil
    }
}

func imagePath() -> String? {
    let rootPath = rootFilePath()
    if let uPath = rootPath {
        return "\(uPath)/\(imageId).png"
    }
    else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Any movement on this?  I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: Nope... nothing yet. And the guy on this post claims he doesn't have the problem at all, though I don't believe it, I feel like the file system is just locked down with a passcode on -- though I haven't yet scoured the docs. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25844434/431271

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out!  You need to set the file permissions accordingly:

```
NSFileManager *fm = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSDictionary *attribs = @{NSFileProtectionKey : NSFileProtectionNone};
NSError *unprotectError = nil;

BOOL unprotectSuccess = [fm setAttributes:attribs
                             ofItemAtPath:[containerURL path]
                                    error:&unprotectError];
if (!unprotectSuccess) {
    NSLog(@"Unable to remove protection from file! %@", unprotectError);
}
```

In many cases you wouldn't normally want to do this, but because the information is intended to be viewed from the lock screen, I'm OK with removing file protection.

Comment: Can you share the full code? If 'containerURL' is nil, then how are you setting an attribute on it?

Comment: @strangetimes If it is nil, then you have a bigger problem than trying to unprotect a file that isn't there.  I recommend asking a new question.

Comment: Sorry I thought you said above that it is in fact returning nil? Do you unprotect it when it gives you a nil or do you do it before when the device isn't locked?

Comment: @strangetimes ideally you unprotect it when you are writing it.  This particular code is for when it was written previously and it needs to be removed.  This can only be done when the device is unlocked.

Comment: Thanks Wayne. Got it. So that's what I need. My SQLite db was created already and need to remove the security on top. Is this a permanent change then, I'm guessing it is.